# Why use a staging area in Git?

Tags: git, git-stage

I am new to Git, and would like to know where it would be useful to use a staging area, instead of directly committing the changed files.

Comment: For example if you want to break the changes into several commits so that they make sense.

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/69178/74113

Comment: I'm going to close this as a duplicate as phd's comment (which will vanish) says, but it's worth noting that when you run `git commit <file>`, what Git is doing is, in effect, `git add`-ing that file *to* the staging area, and then using the staging area to commit. The way Git is built internally, you *always* commit through a stage. Git simply chooses to expose it, so that you have to learn about it, instead of keeping it hidden and automatic as in (e.g.) Mercurial.

Comment: when I'm using git in 80% cases I don't want to commit all changes in a single commit.

Answer (score 0):

It's the only clean way to "freeze" your local copy state without doing a commit, and so to unstage something is the only way to undo a local edit without "rewriting the history".

I use it a lot, for instance when I'm in a state where things works but what I've done is still not ready for a commit that makes sense.

You can obviously obtain something similar in other ways, for instance doing partial commits in a local, feature branch, and doing a `git merge --squash branchname` at the end (and then removing the branch), when the feature/fix is ready.